# How do I properly arrange my Gemfile for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to install vote-fu into my rails 3 project.

The documentation ( for rails 2 ) says to install it into my environments.rb file as so..

```
config.gem "peteonrails-vote_fu", :lib => 'vote_fu', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

How could I convert that to rails 3 for the Gemfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gemfile:

gem 'vote_fu'

http://gems.github.com is no more. The standard gem host is http://gemcutter.org which Bundler is setup to use by default, so you don't need to specify source. Vote_fu is hosted on gemcutter (see: http://rubygems.org/gems/vote_fu).

For reference, you would convert the options in config.gem like this:

:source => 'example.com' changes to (on its own line in Gemfile):

```
source 'example.com'
```

:lib => 'mylib' changes to:

```
gem 'libkey_mylib', :require => 'mylib'
```

Comment: That gemcutter link leads to an actual site about real gem cutters :)

Comment: Sam, can I specify a specific source for a specific Gem then? I have a gem source added in my private repository, but right now I'm bumping the version number from the RG one so that my app picks out the one with my mods - but if they bump their version, their would be chosen I would assume.